# Laravel App error 503 after deployed to EC2

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-ec2, fastcgi

I have laravel app.. It's work normally when I run on my localhost server. but when I deploy to EC2 Instance.. it work normal until I do login .. and after login.. I got this following error
[image]

I still don't understand what's wrong with my application. and I try to open error log on the server and the error log said like this following image:
[image]

something wrong with Fast CGI maybe.. but I still not fixing this issue yet.
Anyway my EC2 type is **t3a.nano**, is it possible to causing the error.

Hopefully you can help me guys.. I was looking for solution about this error almost 2 days.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what server your using ? and add config file in question

Comment: @Kamlesh Iam using apache but installed with bitnami package. which config file you  mean @kamlesh?

Comment: in server you have installed `bitnami package` is this windows server ?

Comment: no it just Debian Linux

Comment: oh i used manually install `php,ngiinx,mysql,composer`  no idea about `bitnami package`

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem may be fixed by cache cleaning

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Sometimes this command not give result. Then you can try this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r /your_site_dir/storage/framework/cache/data/*
rm -r /your_site_dir/storage/framework/views/*
```

Comment: I already try to ctrl + F5 on chrome but it still not working thanks @Андрей Беспалов

Comment: I mean laravel cache. Please execute this command in your website root directory: php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear

Comment: I already try do this `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear` but it still doesn't work

Comment: it show this error  `cannot remove 'storage/framework/cache/data/*': No such file or directory`